# Display lists and folders from sharepoint in WPF treeview

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I want to display all lists with their folders in a WPF tree view.

The lists are displaying well, but not the folders (i am only having a one level treeview).

This is how i am fetching the lists and folders:

```
   ListCollection lists = site.Lists;
                IEnumerable<SP.List> listsCollection =
                    context.LoadQuery(
                                lists.Include(l => l.Title, l => l.Id, l => l.RootFolder.Folders.Include(
                                    Folder => Folder.Name))
                                     .Where(list => !list.Hidden && list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary));

           context.executeQuery();
```

i am adding `lists` to my treeview itemssource.

and this is my treeview xaml:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lists}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Folder}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

folders are not displayed,help.

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner `DataTemplate` also a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and set the [HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemssource.aspx) to the property that holds the folders.

**Update:**

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lists}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Folder}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />                                            
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Look at the inner HierarchicalDataTemplate, there is also an ItemsSource that is responsible to get the sub-items.

Comment: can you add the example please

Comment: thanks, almost there, but not yet, still one level result,  actually, to get the folders of a list we use  list.RootFolder.Folders (which is a collection of folders), should we put another value of the Itemssource and textblock of the inner Hierarchicaldatatemplate?

Comment: @Zee99: Yes, this will be probaly the problem. Concentrate first on the ItemsSource. Don't know your structure but try out ItemsSource="{Binding RootFolder.Folders}" maybe this is it. For the Textblock I assume it will be also something like Text="{Binding Title}", like in the outer declaration. Just play around a little.

Comment: tried RootFolder.Folders and tried Lists.RootFolder.Folders, still no luck

Comment: Try ItemsSource="{Binding}". This will look if your items-object of the upper level is enumerable and iteraters over its items. If this does not work, I regret that I can not help, because I don't know your object-structure. From the WPF-perspective, the tree should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you the MVVM approach for managing a treeview. The approach is described in this very good article :
[Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)

Treeview in WPF is quickly painful... the mvvm approach shift the management in a class of your own and it's actually easier to manage.